# Eliminar estilos del padre en un tema hijo de wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

estoy desarrollando una página que va a tener una tienda on-line. La tienda quiero usar el tema storefront de los propios desarrolladores de woocommerce, pero la parte que no es tienda quería usar una página ya desarrollada.

Para hacerlo he creado un tema hijo de storefront, y estoy desarrollando la página de inicio en front-page.php, pero no consigo impedir que me cargue el style.css del tema padre en esa página y me genera conflictos en los css.

Lo he intentado usando este archivo functions.php del tema hijo

```php
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'storefront-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'inkustudio_scripts_styles');
function inkustudio_scripts_styles() {    

    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '-child/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '8.0.1');
        wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('agency', 'bootstrap'), array(), '1.0.0');
        wp_enqueue_style('agency', get_template_directory_uri(). '-child/css/agency.css', array('bootstrap'), '8.0.1');
        wp_enqueue_style('agency', get_template_directory_uri(). '-child/css/agency.css', array('bootstrap'), '9.0.1');
        wp_dequeue_style( 'storefront-style');
        wp_deregister_style( 'storefront-style' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'child-style');
        wp_deregister_style( 'child-style' );

        wp_enqueue_script('agencyjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/js/agency.js', array('jqueryp'), '1.0.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jqueryp'), '1.0.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script('jqueryeasing', get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/js/jquery.easing.min.js', array('jqueryp'), '1.0.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jqueryp', get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/js/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    }else{

    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

usa la función `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` para referirte a los estilos del directorio del tema hijo, con `get_template_directory_uri()` haces referencia al tema padre